# MySQL - Duplicate entry error when trying to add new column

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I have a MySQL database with a table that has 2 million rows using innodb engine. I want to add another column, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Error 1062: Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY' SQL Statement: ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`table`  ADD COLUMN `country` VARCHAR(35) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `email`
```

How can I add the column without getting this error?

**EDIT:** Table definition

```
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
user_id varchar(45) NOT NULL,   
first_name varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,   
last_name varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,   
gender varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,   
email varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,   
created_at bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,   
updated_at bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`user_id`),   
UNIQUE KEY `user_id_UNIQUE` (`user_id`),   
KEY `first_name` (`first_name`),   
KEY `last_name` (`last_name`)
```

**EDIT #2:** SHOW INDEXES output

```
Table       Non_unique  Key_name        Seq_in_index  Column_name     Collation  Cardinality Index_type
table       0           PRIMARY         1             id              A          3516446     BTREE      
table       0           PRIMARY         2             user_id         A          3516446     BTREE
table       0           user_id_UNIQUE  1             user_id         A          3516446     BTREE
table       1           first_name      1             first_name      A          390716      BTREE  
table       1           last_name       1             last_name       A          439555      BTREE
```

Comment: Try removing the `after old_column`.

Comment: Tried it, still produced the same error

Comment: Can you show your current table definition?

Comment: What does `SHOW INDEXES FROM mydb.table` return?

Comment: It's strange to define your PK over `(id,user_id)` here: it permits you to have multiple records with the same `id` value provided that their `user_id` values differ, however if you always rely on `AUTO_INCREMENT` then `id` values will necessarily differ.  Furthermore, `user_id` values must always differ because of the `user_id_UNIQUE` constraint.  This arrangement can lead to strange data, but I can't see how there can be duplicate PK values of `''` unless the index has been corrupted.

Comment: @George Shows the two primary keys `id` and `user_id`, the unique key for `user_id`, and the two keys `first_name` and `last_name`

Comment: @Hank please update your question with the full results of the `SHOW INDEXES` command as there might be something wrong with your keys.

Comment: @Hank is that all you get with the `SHOW INDEXES`? I was mostly interested in the `Sub_part` field which, when wrongly set, can cause this weird behavior you are experiencing.

Comment: `Sub_part` is Null for all rows

Comment: I have exactly the same problem... @Hank did you find a solution?

Comment: @Hank have you found any solution to this yet? I've got the same problem with my table.

Comment: My problem is solved by not specifying where to insert the column (adding it at the end of the table)!

Answer (score 27):

it solution will lock table on write, but often suitable for solving the problem if table is not very big

```
LOCK TABLES my_table WRITE;

ALTER TABLE my_table 
ADD COLUMN `ts` DATETIME NULL AFTER `id`;

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Answer (score 20):

As described in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-online-ddl-limitations.html#:%7E:text=The%20following%20limitations%20apply%20to,NULL%20constraints%20on%20the%20table.), When running an online `ALTER TABLE` operation:

> ... the thread that runs the
> ALTER TABLE operation will apply an “online log” of DML operations
> that were run concurrently on the same table from other connection
> threads. When the DML operations are applied, it is possible to
> encounter a duplicate key entry error (ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate
> entry), even if the duplicate entry is only temporary and would be
> reverted by a later entry in the “online log”. This is similar to the
> idea of a foreign key constraint check in InnoDB in which constraints
> must hold during a transaction.

Comment: Best description of error. You can avoid this error with this tool : https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/3.0/pt-online-schema-change.html

Answer (score 9):

If it's not something a program needs to do (altering tables dynamically), then just wait a moment and then try again! It worked for me. :) I guess there are some InnoDB-specific processes/states (maybe still processing another ALTER queried just a moment ago?), during which the ALTER command would fail, and you just need to catch a moment when it succeeds.

Comment: I had the same issue, and waiting for a long running process to end helped, so it might be a locking issue with a wrong error message.

Comment: This was our case as well. When we ran again after sometime it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I've runned the same code and it works fine.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1937e

As a solution, I would try to recreate the table , copy the data into it, and then switch tables using rename.

- If that **doesn't work** then it's clear that it's a bug with your current mysql configuration, and we'll need more details to figure it out or at least reproduce it (mysql version, mysql config, database settings, the actual data, etc.).
- If it **works** then it probably was a problem with tables or indexes and here are a few things you can check (you can also start with these if you don't wish to recreate the table):

  1. Check that you don't have any triggers that are causing other inserts
  2. Check that you are just creating a column and not adding other keys/indexes
  3. Check that the auto_increment value is not overflowing (for int it's over 2,000,000,000)

If none of the above, then you probably have a some corrupt data, or you missed to share some details.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there are some other ALTERs or INSERTs which are still processing.

First, to check the processing triggers with this following queries:

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
SELECT * FROM information_schema.INNODB_TRX\G
```

Then, kill the locked query by trx_mysql_thread_id: 132092 for example:

```
KILL 132092;
```

Finally, here‘s a solution - [OnlineSchemaChange (OSC)](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysqlatfacebook/mysqlatfacebook/tools/files/head:/osc). It built by Facebook supports online alter MySQL table schema with minimal impact.

Answer (score 0):

use change column

ALTER TABLE `database`.`table_name` 
CHANGE COLUMN `id` `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

Answer (score 0):

Use `percona toolkit` to change db scheme without needing to lock tables: https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/3.0/pt-online-schema-change.html

This allows to continue updating db while scheme change is being applied. This especially useful for large dbs where updating scheme can take a while.