# Receiving error code 1062 when no duplicate column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update a table with the following query:

```
alter table main_iteminstance add offer_last_updated DATETIME default null
```

> Error Code: 1062
>     Duplicate entry 'https://itunes.apple.com/fr/movie/id1000108161' for key >'store_url'
>
> Execution Time : 0 sec
>     Transfer Time  : 0 sec
>      Total Time     : 40 min 24 sec

The odd thing is that there is no duplicate here. I checked the database and there's only one entry for that, so the error seems out of place. Has anyone ever run into something similar?

Comment: It should be related to the primary key

Comment: You might find some of these answers useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22580529/mysql-duplicate-entry-error-when-trying-to-add-new-column

Comment: @EdmCoff "try again" seems like to suggested solution here. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I thought cutd's explanation made sense and Anton Larchenkov's answer might help. Although if this is a one-off, then I guess most people seem to have success with "try again."

Comment: @EdmCoff agreed -- for us, it actually worked (with zero changes) the second time we tried it.